# Iframe Restritions

Tags: iframe, http-headers

Is there any documentation that explains what you cannot do, to make an iframe unusable?

> You cannot use facebook iframe because of x-frame-options is deny
>
> Twitter you cannot use iframe because an ancestor violates the following content security policy directive:"frame-ancestors" self

Is there anywhere I can check what can and can't be set to accept an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are two HTTP Headers that can be used to prevent a website from being loaded as an iframe on other websites:

## X-Frame-Options

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`.

The possible values are:

- `deny`
- `sameorigin`
- `allow-from`*`uri`*

You can read more about what they each do [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

**Note that according to the specification, `frame-ancestors` takes precedence over `X-Frame-Options`:**

> The frame-ancestors directive obsoletes the X-Frame-Options header. If a resource has both policies, the frame-ancestors policy SHOULD be enforced and the X-Frame-Options policy SHOULD be ignored.

From the example you posted, it seems like Facebook has `X-Frame-Options: deny` as a response header, which prevents it from being loaded in an iframe from anywhere (in browsers that support this header).

## Content-Security-Policy

Using either:

- `frame-ancestors` which restricts what domains can embed this website in an iframe

  > The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) frame-ancestors directive specifies valid parents that may embed a page using `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, or `<applet>`.

  The main difference with `X-Frame-Options` is that

  > many user agents implement SAMEORIGIN such that it only matches against the top-level document’s location. This directive checks each ancestor. If any ancestor doesn’t match, the load is cancelled.
- `frame-src` which restricts what domains this website can embed in an iframe

  > The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) frame-src directive specifies valid sources for nested browsing contexts loading using elements such as `<frame>` and `<iframe>`.

You can read more about [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) and [frame-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) on MDN.

From the example you posted, it seems like Twitter has `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'`, which means that that website can only be embedded on the same domain.